# Django django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

I have an app for surveys. I am trying to import my model in `views.py` and its giving an error.

My code is:

`settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'survey.apps.SurveyConfig',
    'survey.urls',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

`urls.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('survey/', include('survey.urls')),
]
```

`survey/urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.list_surveys, name='list-surveys'),
    path('create/', views.create_survey, name='list-surveys'),
]
```

`survey/views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import MultipleChoiceQuestion

surveys = [
    {
        "id": "S001",
        "questions": [
            ["How much do you like Userfacet?", 1],
            ["How much do you like frontend?", 0],
            ["How much do you like backend?", 2],
            ["How much do you like fullstack?", 0],
            ["How much do you like Userfacet?", 3],
            ["How much do you like frontend?", 0],
            ["How much do you like backend?", 4],
            ["How much do you like fullstack?", 0],
            ["How much do you like Userfacet?", 5],
            ["How much do you like frontend?", 0],
            ["How much do you like backend?", 6],
            ["How much do you like fullstack?", 0],
            ["How much do you like Userfacet?", 7],
            ["How much do you like frontend?", 0],
            ["How much do you like backend?", 8],
            ["How much do you like fullstack?", 0],
            ["How much do you like Userfacet?", 9],
            ["How much do you like frontend?", 0],
            ["How much do you like backend?", 10],
            ["How much do you like fullstack?", 0]
        ]
    }
]

# Create your views here.
def list_surveys(request):
    context = { "surveys": {} }
    for question in MultipleChoiceQuestion.objects.all():
        try:
            context["surveys"][question.survey_id].append(question)
        except KeyError:
            context["surveys"][question.survey_id] = []
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'survey/list_surveys.html', context = context)

def create_survey(request):
    return render(request, 'survey/create_survey.html')
```

`survey/models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class MultipleChoiceQuestion(models.Model):
    class MultipleChoiceAnswer(models.IntegerChoices):
        NONE = 0, 'NONE'
        ONE = 1, 'One'
        TWO = 2, 'TWO'
        THREE = 3, 'THREE'
        FOUR = 4, 'FOUR'
        FIVE = 5, 'FIVE'
        SIX = 6, 'SIX'
        SEVEN = 7, 'SEVEN'
        EIGHT = 8, 'EIGHT'
        NINE = 9, 'NINE'
        TEN = 10, 'TEN'
    survey_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    answer = models.IntegerField(choices=MultipleChoiceAnswer.choices, default=MultipleChoiceAnswer.NONE)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Question'

class Similarity(models.Model):
    survey_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_2', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Value: ' + str(self.value)
```

`survey/admin.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MultipleChoiceQuestion, Similarity

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(MultipleChoiceQuestion)
admin.site.register(Similarity)
```

---

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jaide\Documents\marks_management_system\django_app\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\jaide\Documents\marks_management_system\django_app\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\jaide\Documents\marks_management_system\django_app\survey\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\jaide\Documents\marks_management_system\django_app\survey\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import MultipleChoiceQuestion
  File "C:\Users\jaide\Documents\marks_management_system\django_app\survey\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 57, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 129, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

When trying to call `django.setup()` myself, I get another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\jaide\Documents\marks_management_system\django_app\survey\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\jaide\Documents\marks_management_system\django_app\survey\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 83, in populate
    raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: your installed apps should come after django's

Comment: @Sayse still giving the app error.

Comment: You're showing two errors here, which are you talking about?

Comment: @Sayse the app one. The first one.

Comment: I know its trivial and you have probably tried... But have you tried registering the app as 'survey' instead of the 'survey.apps.SurveryConfig' and 'survey.urls'?

Comment: Oh my god @Kolay I did not need to put `survey.urls` there. I removed it and it works. Just keep the `survey.apps.SurveyConfig`. What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion of 'survey.urls' in the INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py is likely causing the issue. The INSTALLED_APPS list is meant for specifying Django applications, and 'survey.urls' is a URL configuration, not an app.

You should include only the app name in INSTALLED_APPS, not the URL configuration. In your case, it should be:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'survey.apps.SurveyConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]